# Resizing UIView with animation, subview won't animate

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview

Using UIView's `animateWithDuration:animations:completion:`, I'm resizing a UIView and a subview of that UIView which is a subclass of UITableView.

The UIView resizes fine, but the UITableView doesn't. It does move around a little, but the frame does not update properly and reverts to its original state.

**Edit:** if I move the resizing to the completion block.... it works. What gives?

[image]

```
    tweetTable.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    [tweetTable endUpdates];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:DURATION animations:^{
        CGRect leftFrame = leftPane.frame;
        leftFrame.size.width = self.view.frame.size.width - MARGIN;
        leftPane.frame = leftFrame;
        leftPaneButton.frame = leftFrame;

        CGRect tweetFrame = tweetTable.frame;
        tweetFrame.size.width = leftPane.frame.size.width;
        NSLog(@"%f to %f", tweetTable.frame.size.width, leftPane.frame.size.width);
        tweetTable.frame = tweetFrame;
        tweetTable.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        tweetTable.alpha = 0.5f;

        sideInfo.center = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width - MARGIN + (sideInfo.frame.size.width / 2), sideInfo.center.y);
        rightPaneButton.center = sideInfo.center;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        leftExtended = TRUE;
        [tweetTable beginUpdates];
    }];
```

Answer (score 0):

Check in your storyboard if the `UIView` has **Autoresize Subviews** checked. That means that it resizes all of its subviews when the view itself gets resized. That would explain why it works in the completion block.

Comment: It was checked, however unchecking it has no effect.

Comment: Are you working with Autolayout? You can pin the width of the UITableView to the UIView width and then you don't have to change the frame of it by hand.